# Program not Installed & java.lang.SecurityException 

Tags: android

I've been working on an application for the past week or so, and when I went to test it the other day, my console read the following to me:

```
[2010-06-08 17:13:36 - CellSafe2] ------------------------------
[2010-06-08 17:13:36 - CellSafe2] Android Launch!
[2010-06-08 17:13:36 - CellSafe2] adb is running normally.
[2010-06-08 17:13:36 - CellSafe2] Performing com.ryan.android.cellsafe.Activity activity launch
[2010-06-08 17:13:36 - CellSafe2] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD1'
[2010-06-08 17:13:36 - CellSafe2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD1'
[2010-06-08 17:13:38 - CellSafe2] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2010-06-08 17:13:38 - CellSafe2] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2010-06-08 17:14:16 - CellSafe2] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2010-06-08 17:14:16 - CellSafe2] Device API version is 6 (Android 2.0.1)
[2010-06-08 17:14:16 - CellSafe2] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-06-08 17:14:16 - CellSafe2] Uploading CellSafe2.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-06-08 17:14:16 - CellSafe2] Installing CellSafe2.apk...
[2010-06-08 17:14:31 - CellSafe2] Success!
[2010-06-08 17:14:32 - CellSafe2] Starting activity com.ryan.android.cellsafe.Activity on device 
[2010-06-08 17:14:38 - CellSafe2] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.ryan.android.cellsafe/.Activity }
[2010-06-08 17:14:38 - CellSafe2] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ryan.android.cellsafe/.Activity } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES
```

The icon for the program is present in my emulator, and I have added  android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES to my Manifest.

For some reason the emulator tells me that the program is not installed "on this phone" when I try to run the program using the icon in the emulator. Which I find interesting considering that the console says it was installed successfully...

Any ideas as to why it isn't working? I'd really appreciate some help as this is due for one of my classes on Monday of next week.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain you cannot hold the `ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES` permission. More importantly, I am not aware of anything in the SDK that uses the `ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES` permission.